# TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to get up and running with [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/), but I run into a problem when I try to move navigation items into their own components.

Here's a Stack Navigator inside a APP.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import S1 from './Src/Screen/s1';
import S2 from './Src/Screen/s2';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="s2"
          component={S2}
          options={{title: 's2'}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="s1" component={S1} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>,
     <S1></S1>,
     <S2></S2>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here's a  s1.js:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, ScrollView ,StyleSheet,View,Text,Button, ImageBackground,Dimensions} from "react-native";

const S1 = ({ navigation })=> {
    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}} >
            <ScrollView>
                       <Text style={styles.myTitle}>Expore The {'\n'}Universe</Text>      
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
    }
```

Here's a  s2.js:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, ScrollView ,StyleSheet,View,Text,Button, ImageBackground,Dimensions} from "react-native";

const S2 = ({navigation})=> {
    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}} >
            <ScrollView>
                        <View style={styles.buttonex}>
                        <Button 
                               onPress={() => navigation.navigate('s1')}
                               title="Ex"
                         />
                        </View>                    
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
    }
```

When I press on icons with `"onPress={() => navigation.navigate(...)}`"I get the following errors:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined, js engine: hermes`

I want to navigate from s2 to s1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related to Hermes or any other JavaScript engine. it's about your S1,S2 placement.

```js
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="s2"
          component={S2}
          options={{title: 's2'}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="s1" component={S1} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>,
     <S1></S1>,
     <S2></S2>
  );
```

Look at the last two lines. your S1 and S2 are out of the navigator context. You must read carefully [navigate docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating) and implement precisely like the example. then try to change it. So:

```js
// remove these two
     <S1></S1>,
     <S2></S2>
```

**And** I highly recommend using hooks instead of using props. like:

```js
const { navigate, goBack, ...rest } = useNavigation();
```